# ¿Como puedo mostrar datos en un Modal que contiene una tabla en Spring boot?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

Saludos a la comunidad

Tengo el siguiente codigo

en el controlador

```
 @GetMapping("/cliente")
    public String listarClientes(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("clientes", clienteService.listarCliente());
        
        return "mantenimiento/cliente";
    }
```

en mi jsp

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="cliente" class="control-label col-md-1">Cliente</label>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cliente" autofocus />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input  class="btn btn-primary nBtn31" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" value="Buscar cliente..." />
                                </div>
                                

</div>
 
<div class="myForm31">
        <form:form  action="" method="GET"  modelAttribute="clientes" >
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" 
        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        
            
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Buscar Clientes</h5>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nBtn31">
                  
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="credentialsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>             
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                    
            </tr>
        
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${clientes}" var="cliente">
                <tr>
                    <td>${cliente.idcliente}</td>
                    <td>${cliente.nombre}</td>
                    <td>${cliente.apepaterno}</td>
                    <td>${cliente.apematerno}</td>              
                </tr>
            
            </c:forEach>
        
        </tbody>
        
        
        
    </table>
             </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="guardar"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
           
        </div>
        
        </form:form>
     </div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.myForm31 #exampleModal .nBtn31').on('click', function(){
        
        $.ajax({
                url:'../mantenimiento/cliente/',
                method: 'GET',
                 success: data => {
                        var table = $('#exampleModal').find('.table tbody');
                        for (var i in data) {
                            table.append('<tr><td>' + data[i].idcliente + '</td><td>' + data[i].nombre + '</td><td>' + data[i].apepaterno + '</td><td>' + data[i].apenaterno + '</td></tr>');
                        }
                    }
                    
        })
    });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el modal no me muestra la lista de clientes si alguien me ´puede apoyar o dar una idea de como puedo solucionar espero su ayuda gracias

Comment: No eres nuevo en SOes, sabes que para obtener una respuesta debes proporcionar código. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar cómo obtienes la lista de clientes, cómo tratas de agregarla a la tabla y un ejemplo con al menos 2 clientes.

Comment: en controlador puede usted observar que obtiene la lista de cliente. lo que yo quiero es eso agregarlo a una tabla pero en un modal

Comment: Parece que _clientes_ está vacía. Desconozco Java, pero supongo que debe haber alguna forma de mostrar en pantalla el contenido de una variable o usar el debugger de tu IDE para observarlas.